# best browser for developer Firefox or Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

Which browser suits best from developers point of view,Firefox or Internet explorer.

Comment: Argumentative; but if they answer you, most people here will tell you "anything but IE". In particular, Firefox + Firebug is a quite good combination. Also, even if you don't develop on IE, it might be advisable to check on one (unless it goes counter to your religion. My religion is "screw those IE nuts, i don't want to do everything twice" - once for IE and once for everything else; but sometimes I am just not given freedom of religion.)

Comment: Whatever happens, at least make this question CW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use either Firefox or Chrome as your main development browser and then test at regular intervals with other browsers you need to support. The main reason for going with them over IE is the improve support for debugging CSS and JavaScript (using either Firebug or Chrome's developer tools). Perhaps support for this will improve with IE9 but for now it's painful.

It's worth pointing out that Chrome has a very useful extension called Speed Tracer that will help you diagnose bottlenecks in your web application. Quite useful for rich client webapps with lots of JavaScript and dynamic HTML layout.

[Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/)

Answer (score 2):

FireFox, it has great plugins to help you develop and test. IE is far more limited.

Comment: Also firefox is avaiable for all major OS while IE is only limited to Windows. Although IE can be installed on linux using WINE but native support has edge.

Answer (score 1):

i prefer Firefox. you got so many developer tools such as FireBug, YSlow etc. thought their equivalent tools are avaliable in IE but they are not so feature rich and user friendly

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/).

Comment: How could we forget good old Lynx!

Comment: I want to downvote this... I don't understand why this is even a recommendation, except to maybe test semantics of markup?

Comment: it was a joke and not a recommendation. downvotes are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In a Developer's point of view you HAVE to support all major browsers ;-) unless there is a reason to ignore a browser. For example I develop mostly intranet portals and company guidelines is to concentrate more on IE as users are not allowed to install other browsers.

Both Firefox and IE (8) have good developer tools namely Firebug and Developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

all of them. seriously.
even if you write your code to be W3C standard compliant - every browser has its quirks.
test on all of them. it's good practice.
but at a general level - firefox has the best plugins for developers (firebug, live HTTP headers, and more).